# Python CDROM Production

Tags: python, adobe, media, dvd, cd-rom

I have been using Macromedia / Adobe Director & Lingo since 1998. I am extremely familiar with using this software to create CDROMs and DVDs and also have a good knowledge of design elements and their integration such as flash videos, images & audio etc.

I am always keen to explore other technologies and understand that Python can be used to create CDROMs.

I have tried Googling some information on this subject but to no avail. Does anyone know the pros and cons of Python CDROM production? Is it capable of delivering such media rich experiences as Adobe Director? What are the limitations?

Any help / resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Python  is a programming language -- not much like Adobe Director.  CDROM production is usually a simple matter of creating a directory of content and burning the CD with an OS utility.  Are you talking about building the content?  What kind of content are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

**sounds grim to me**

I presume you mean an auto-run executable for Windows that runs when a CDROM is inserted, to provide some sort of flashy popup experience thing.

I would stick with flash. You [can make Python executables](http://www.py2exe.org/), and you can use them for this, but flash or a similar tech seems like a better alternative.

I *suppose* Cairo SVG rendering/Animation and Python would work theoretically, but really, you would be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't the tool you are looking for... [waves hand across in front of Mindblip's face]

Stick with Director or try Flash with either MPlayer or Zinc.

Comment: Move along... (15 chars minimum)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not asking so much for mass-copying of CDs/DVDs (which is what I assumed from reading the title), but for a Python-based replacement for Adobe Director? I don't think anything like that presently exists.

However, Python could certainly help you out with the scripting and control of various elements in the production process -- for example, taking the tedium out of assembling lots of files together into one final package. You'd have to be more specific about what you're looking for, though.